# CSS open-quote shows 1 quotation mark

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following CSS to add open quotes before a paragraph:

```
blockquote {
  padding: 22px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
  font-size: 15px;
}
blockquote:before {
  color: #111;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
```

When I add more than two blockquotes they show only 1 quotation mark. I want to show 2 `"`. I can't figure out why this is happening. Please see jsfiddle for example.

http://jsfiddle.net/yg7j5mkm/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You must close the quotes before open another one.

Here a workaround: Close quotes, but invisible.

```css
blockquote {
  padding: 22px;
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
  font-size: 15px;
}
blockquote:before {
  color: #111;
  content: open-quote;
  font-size: 4em;
  line-height: 0;
  vertical-align: -0.4em;
}
blockquote:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  content: close-quote;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p style="display:inline;">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p style="display:inline;">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
  <p style="display:inline;">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works :) I don't think there is a need to repeat the blockquote styling in the `:after` selector.

Comment: For future reference, this page shows a simpler way, use `blockquote:after {content: no-close-quote}` - http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/start-using-quotation-marks-the-correct-way--webdesign-16905](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/start-using-quotation-marks-the-correct-way--webdesign-16905)

Comment: @jtotheh thanks for sharing, but the link seems broken

Comment: @rnrneverdies whoops, try this? [http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/start-using-quotation-marks-the-correct-way--webdesign-16905](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/start-using-quotation-marks-the-correct-way--webdesign-16905)

Answer (score 5):

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#quotes-insert:

> *Which pair of quotes is used depends on the nesting level of quotes: the number of occurrences of 'open-quote' in all generated text before the current occurrence, minus the number of occurrences of 'close-quote'. If the depth is 0, the first pair is used, if the depth is 1, the second pair is used, etc.*

Since you are not using `close-quote` here, for your second `blockquote` you have *one* occurrence of `open-quote` before it, and none of `close-quote` – meaning, the depth is 1, so the quotes you specified as second pair are used. (“Nesting” does not necessarily mean nested `blockquote` elements by this definition.)

To fix this, use `close-quote` as well – and hide them if you don’t want them to show:

```
blockquote:after {
  content: close-quote;
  visibility:hidden; /* to hide closing quote – don’t use display:none here,
                        because that would mean close-quote is absent again */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yg7j5mkm/2/

Answer (score 1):

In `blockquote:after` you set the `content` to `no-close-quote`:

```
blockquote:after {
  content: no-close-quote
}
```

Here is a snippet:

```css
  blockquote {
      padding: 22px;
      quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
      font-size: 15px;
  }
  blockquote:before {
      color: #111;
      content: open-quote;
      font-size: 4em;
      line-height: 0;
      vertical-align: -0.4em;
  }
  
  /* Add this */
  blockquote:after {
      content: no-close-quote;
  }
```

```html
<blockquote>
    <p style="display:inline;">Blockquote 1</p>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
    <p style="display:inline;">Blockquote 2</p>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this?

```
content: '\201C';
```

It's not as semantic but specifying the `quotes:` rule overrides any l10n, anyway.